# Access db missing msado15.dll when run by end-user

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a script-heavy Access db that I recently sent out to the end-users for bug testing.  The scripts mainly read data, add/update/remove from internal tables, and interact with a shared drive.

They came back immediately with a report that the most important part can't run due to a missing/broken reference to **'msado15.dll' version 6.1** (aka Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library).  This brings 2 questions:

1. Why would this library exist on my machine but not on theirs?  As far as I know, all our machines had the same standard Office install package.  Is it because I have SQL Server and they don't?
2. I think I've found an alternative, **msado28.tlb** (aka Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library), which seems to work just as well, but I haven't tested on the user's machines.  Is this a good substitute?

Comment: If you must use early binding for ADO, version 2.8 is a better choice because it should be available on all your XP and Windows 7 client machines.  I don't know all the details regarding ADO 6.1 ... it's not part of SQL Server; I think it maybe comes in as a Win 7 SP to upgrade from ADO 6.0.  You shouldn't need to worry about ADO version differences if you can switch to early binding for ADO.

Comment: @HansUp, Thanks for the background info.

Comment: I wrote that last sentence wrong.  I meant you shouldn't need to worry about ADO version differences if you can switch to *late* binding for ADO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the library in the distributed version? You could use late binding:

```
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

It is usually easiest to develop with early binding and distribute with late binding.

Comment: Yup, I've always liked the early binding for development.  Should I do this in addition to changing the reference?  Because even if I do this, when I open the db on their machines, the reference menu still says missing reference.

Comment: Get rid of the library reference altogether, add in all the late binding stuff, making sure you have set up your constants, compile and test.

Comment: +1 Early binding is great for dev work as you get the intellisense prompt's, which unless you have a photographic memory are very handy. But I've recently strictly tried to release everything late bound as the reference simply need exist in one version and doesn't have to be an exact match, obviously with ADO there are a handful of versions (1.2 - 2.8) or something like that.